How to Add shapes like Rectangle/Line inside docx file using open xml sdk in dot net
I want to add shapes like Rectangle with red color fill with given width/height at given x,y coordinates in ms word file by creating fresh new file through open xml sdk in dot net.
I did not found any thing on stackoverflow/ Microsoft documentation. If any one know please share the code to how to add basic shape.
I tried using chatgpt but no luck.

One thing you can do: make a document with a single shape, get the Open SDK v2.5 productivity tool ( https://github.com/dotnet/Open-XML-SDK/releases/tag/v2.5 ) and see if it will generate the necessary code for that shape. Then experiment...

thanks, it is generating lots of code for just one rectangle but  no issues I will remove unwanted code.
